# Coordinates of a point between two other points with a exact distance from one of them

Tags: trigonometry

In this situation, I want the coordinates of the point C, I already know the coordinates of A and B, and the distance D (the distance between A and C). C must be on the A-B segment.

[image: situation]

Comment: first construct a unit vector in the required direction, then multiply by the length AC

Comment: $C=(1-t)A+tB, t=\frac{D}{|AB|}$