# % of traversal for a point between two other points along a line

Tags: vectors, analytic-geometry, percentages

I'd like to solve for some "phase" or percentage, involving an arbitrary location (xC, yC) between two points.  I'm not familiar with how to phrase this question, so please excuse my ignorance.  Not sure if this is closer to Trig or LA.  Currently I'd like to solve this for 2D, but might expand to 3D in the future.

[image: point moving along a line]

Comment: I saw this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1275610/coordinates-of-a-point-between-two-other-points-with-a-exact-distance-from-one-o... but it's not quite what I'm asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The movement from $A$ to $B$ is the vector $B-A$.

Some partial amount of that movement is the vector $t(B-A)$, for some value of $t$ between $0$ and $1$.

Making such a movement starting at $A$, you end up at $A + t(B-A)$.

What you want is $A + t(B-A) = C$.  In coordinates:
\begin{align*}
x_A + t(x_B - x_A) &= x_C \\
y_A + t(y_B - y_A) &= y_C
\end{align*}
This is a system of two equations with one unknown, namely $t$.  If $C$ is in fact on the line through $A$ and $B$, this system will have a unique solution; if $C$ is between $A$ and $B$, that solution will be between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: can you also tell me what division of mathematics this belongs to?

Comment: Analytic geometry, and specifically vector methods.  It's sometimes taught as part of a linear algebra course, and it's very useful knowledge when trying to interpret linear algebraic results in geometric terms, but I think most people would say it's not really linear algebra as such.